Can I subscribe to a 1-month XBOX GAME PASS, then run the games with NVIDIA GeForce Now subscription?
Instead of owning a game, can I use a one-month access to that game (XBOX GAME PASS), but instead of downloading and running it on my PC, I'd play it using a remote server (GeForce Now)?
